# Complete: Last year I spent a month in France, I __ dreamt of going there since I was a child

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

What's the correct tense for the space is it present perfect or past perfct and if both were used what would be their meanings? thanks

Comment: Not part of your question, but this is a run-on sentence. The two parts separated by a comma are sentences in their own right, and should either be separated by a semicolon, split into two separate sentences, or linked with a conjunction of some kind.

Answer (score 3):

> Last year I spent a month in France, I ***had dreamt*** of going there since I was a child

The first portion of the sentence is in past so I think it'd take *past perfect.*

*I have dreamt...* would talk about something that is yet to finish in **such case.**